# New mypy error after updating to numpy 1.22

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting, mypy

I Just updated to numpy 1.22.4 (from 1.21) and suddenly mypy (0.910) did not see my software as clean as before.

I read that [from 1.21 to 1.22](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.22.0-notes.html) some big annotation improvements have been done in numpy,  though I do not understand the reason behind these errors I get now.

For example:

1. Value of type "signedinteger[_8bit]" is not indexable

```py
x: np.ndarray 
v: float

# mypy complains: 'error: Value of type "signedinteger[_8Bit]" is not indexable'
xn = np.int8(np.sign(np.atleast_1d(x).ravel() - v))
xn[0]

# mypy does not complain
xn = np.array(np.sign(np.atleast_1d(x).ravel() - v), dtype=np.int8)
xn[0]
```

2. Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "float", variable has type "floating[Any]")

```py
import numpy as np

def get_my_float(flt: float) -> float:
    return flt

# mypy complains: 'error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "float", variable has type "floating[Any]")'
get_my_float(np.average([2, 3])

# mypy does not complain (ugly workaround?)
get_my_float(float(np.average([2, 3]))
```

3. error: "assert_approx_equal" does not return a value

```py
import numpy as np
# calc reference solution as ref
# approximate reference solution as app

# mypy does complain
np.testing.assert_approx_equal(app, ref)

# This error I cannot solve, and had to use # type: ignore to suppress
# mypy does not complain
np.testing.assert_approx_equal(app, ref)  # type: ignore
```

I guess the behavior of 3) is related with some other existing numpy or mypy issues:

- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20191
- https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6549

However, before submitting a new numpy issue for any of 1), 2), 3), I would like to understand if I am doing something wrong, and if there is a better solution to the ones I adopted.